# Converting week numbers to dates

Tags: python, datetime

Say I have a week number of a given year (e.g. week number 6 of 2014).

How can I convert this to the date of the Monday that starts that week?

One brute force solution I thought of would be to go through all Mondays of the year:

```
date1 = datetime.date(1,1,2014)
date2 = datetime.date(12,31,2014)
def monday_range(date1,date2):
    while date1 < date2:
        if date1.weekday() == 0:
            yield date1
        date1 = date1 + timedelta(days=1)
```

and store a hash from the first to the last Monday of the year, but this wouldn't do it, since, the first week of the year may not contain a Monday.

Comment: Have you tried the `datetime` module to see if they have such functionality?

Comment: @sshashank124 yes. I use it extensively, but haven't found a way of doing off-the-shelf. Perhaps I need to go through the entire year to store a hash of dates?

Comment: Maybe something like `7*week_num` and that will be your timedelta in days from Jan 1 or something and then you can find the closest Monday. I'm sorry if it is really vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just feed the data into [`time.asctime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=time.asctime#time.asctime).

```
>>> import time
>>> week = 6
>>> year = 2014
>>> atime = time.asctime(time.strptime('{} {} 1'.format(year, week), '%Y %W %w'))
>>> atime
'Mon Feb 10 00:00:00 2014'
```

---

**EDIT:**
To convert this to a `datetime.date` object:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(atime)).date()
datetime.date(2014, 2, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks! Any way to convert `time.strptime('{} {} 1'.format(year, week), '%Y %W %w')` to a `datetime.date object`?

Comment: Thanks, although this solution suffers from an off-by-one error. if I do  `convert_week_and_year(week=14, year=2014)` I get: `datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 7, 0, 0)`, which is **not** consistent with I expected (see http://whatweekisit.com/). Week = 14 should correspond to March 31st, not April 7th ....

Comment: @user815423426 Yeah, that can be a problem, different platforms having different 'opinions'. Just add +- 7 days is the easiest way to remove that problem.

Comment: Sadly, that last step seems to raise `TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not str` for Python 2.7... Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

All about strptime \ strftime:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

```
mytime.strftime('%U') #for W\C Monday
mytime.strftime('%W') #for W\C Sunday
```

Sorry wrong way around

```
from datetime import datetime
mytime=datetime.strptime('2012W6 MON'. '%YW%U %a')
```

Strptime needs to see both the year and the weekday to do this. I'm assuming you've got weekly data so just add 'mon' to the end of the string.
Enjoy

Comment: For the last one, I get an error. `strptime` does not seem to be defined

Answer (score 5):

A simple function to get the Monday, given a date.

```
def get_monday(dte):
    return dte - datetime.timedelta(days = dte.weekday())
```

Some sample output:

```
>>> get_monday(date1)
datetime.date(2013, 12, 30)
>>> get_monday(date2)
datetime.date(2014, 12, 29)
```

Call this function within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

We can just add the number of weeks to the first day of the year.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

>>> week = 40
>>> year = 2019
>>> date = datetime.date(year,1,1)+relativedelta(weeks=+week)
>>> date
datetime.date(2019, 10, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback and give a different version of the answer @anon582847382 gave, you can do something like the below code if you're creating a function for it and the week number is given like "11-2023":

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

def get_date_from_week_number(str_value):
    temp_str = time.asctime(time.strptime('{} {} 1'.format(str_value[3:7], str_value[0:2]), '%Y %W %w'))
    return datetime.strptime(temp_str, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y').date()
```